# Can a contactor give an inductive kickback?

Tags: inductive, contactor, kickback

I have a [ZBMINI](https://sonoff.tech/product/diy-smart-switches/zbmini/) (not -L) and use it to toggle my heating (2kW). In between I put a [contactor](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/A9c20732-schneider-electric-control-230-240vac/dp/B008XJLGKI/ref=sr_1_8?crid=18EFT4QPTQOUP&keywords=230%20V%202NO%2025%20A&qid=1672090960&refinements=p_76%3A419122031&rnid=419121031&rps=1&sprefix=230v%202no%2025a%2Caps%2C80&sr=8-8) because I trust it to be more safe. The problem is that sometimes it toggles a few times extra. Depending on the amount, the heating is on whilst the switch is off?

Is this caused by inductive kickback as described [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/650235/is-this-caused-by-inductive-kickback)? If so, how do I calculate the snubber size/value?

contactor type: [A9c20732](https://benl.rs-online.com/web/p/contactors/7912929?cm_mmc=BE-PPC-DS3A-_-google-_-DSA_BENL_NL_Automation%20%26%20Control%20Gear_Index-_-Contactors%7C%20Products-_-DYNAMIC%20SEARCH%20ADS&matchtype=&dsa-1677556006074&gclid=Cj0KCQiAq5meBhCyARIsAJrtdr5238uXTH20Yt1C5Mh3AM4vmVKrKMj0Cdek2KB9siGskGeb6fzHDRMaAjEaEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) - [datasheet](https://www.se.com/ww/en/product/download-pdf/A9C20732)

heater type: convector 2kW

The heater does have an optional fan built in. Should I see if this has impact?

Is there a type of contactor that I can use that does not give inductive kickback?

Comment: Please provide a data sheet link to the contactor.

Comment: What is the 2kW heater?  Please use the edit link to put this detail in the question.

Comment: And how are controlling  the contactor?

Comment: The ZBMINI controls the contactor via Home Assistant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bought an RC absorption circuit and put it parallel over my contactor coil. I believe the issue is resolved now. But time will tell.